# Invalid access token (Zoom API)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, zoom-sdk

I am trying to create a meeting on behalf of the logged in, authenticated user.

I've successfully created a user with Devise and Omniauth:

**user.rb**

```
def self.from_omniauth(auth)
      where(provider: auth.provider, uid: auth.uid).first_or_create do |user|
        user.provider = auth.provider
        user.uid = auth.uid
        user.email = auth.info.email
        user.name = auth.info.name
        user.phonenumber = auth.info.phone_number
        user.picurl = auth.info.pic_url
        user.timezone = auth.info.timezone
        user.password = Devise.friendly_token[0,20]
        user.refresh_token = auth.credentials.refresh_token
        user.access_token = auth.credentials.token
      end
  end
```

However, when making the request, I'm consistently getting `HTTPUnauthorized 401: {\"code\":124,\"message\":\"Invalid access token.\"}"`

Here's my controller:

```
def create 
require 'uri'
    require 'net/http'
    require 'openssl'
    url = URI("https://api.zoom.us/v2/users/me/meetings")
    http = Net::HTTP.new(url.host, url.port)
    http.use_ssl = true
    http.verify_mode = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE
    request = Net::HTTP::Post.new(url)
    request["content-type"] = 'application/json'
    request["authorization"] = 'Bearer ' + current_user.access_token

    response = http.request(request)
    puts response.read_body
end
```

Comment: There could be many reasons. The token might be expired. For that you need to use refresh token to get fresh access token. Another possibility is that during oauth flow, you might not have asked enough permission which required to call your API. You should have granted enough permission to call the APIs.

Answer (score 0):

the problem is simple you just have to change the userid, use your username appears in zoom profile page as sign-in email instead of me in the uri.
your current url : "https://api.zoom.us/v2/users/**me**/meetings"
change with this : "https://api.zoom.us/v2/users/**your_email**/meetings".
once you change this just make sure you'vr been created token not expired or create it again after doing this changes and make it valid for atleast 1 day to test and then you can set its expiry custom.